# Redirect to Home/Error View Page in ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to make a custom Error View Page for whenever an error occurs somewhere in my mvc web page. Ideally id want a View from any Controller action to be displayed when an error happens.

I've tried a couple of diffrent ways but none of them caught the exceptions and I got the usual error page when starting my application (after putting in errors on purpose to try it out.)

Currently I just have a Razor View "Error" in my Home Folder and returning the view like normally in the HomeController

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    ...
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public IActionResult Error()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *the usual error page*? Are you running this in the development environment?

Comment: @Misha Morf, Your requirement is not clear! Are you wanting if any exception occurs in the application then it will be redirect to Home Controller `Error` method and here you will handle or log the exception then you will show a generic error message. is it?

Comment: @TanvirArjel Sorry for the confusion, Yeah I dont want the default error message to show, if there is an error somewhere. I want the Error View to be displayed. U get me?

Comment: @KirkLarkin just the normal error page you get directed to when running the project on iis.

Comment: Will you not show an custom error message on Error the View? or the exception message?

Comment: @MischaMorf Are you running the app on development or Production?

Comment: @TanvirArjel If an error occurs, doenst matter what error, I want the HomeController/Error View to be displayed, in which I can make a view saying "an error has occured" or whatever

Comment: @TanvirArjel not sure what u mean by that sorry

Comment: On which environment? On both Production (When the application hosted) or Development (while developing on visual studio)?

Comment: Oh im developing in visual studio and just want to not get the standart error page while running app on localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    ...
}
```

Look at the above configuration. Here while you are developing the application on Visual Studio it will **not redirect to `/Home/Error`** because it it set for other other environment Like Production Environment. Instead it will show the exception details page due to this `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();`

If you want to redirect to `/Home/Error` due to any error on Both `Production` and `Development` environment  then Configure as follows:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
     app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

}
```

Then in the `Error` method :

```
public IActionResult Error()
{
    var pathFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
    Exception exception = pathFeature?.Error; // Here will be the exception details.

    return View();
}
```