# How to redirect user to custom error page when user doesn't give consent during social logon

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

How to redirect user to custom error page when user doesn't give consent during social logon

Currently, we don't have break point anywhere not in startup.cs nor home/index in .net core 3.1

We got post response as below to https://someurl/signin-oidc

AADB2C90273: An invalid response was received : 'Error: access_denied,Error Description: ConsentNotGiven' Correlation ID: b2f05e97-8f27-479c-b99c-cc6f9f7e35c6 Timestamp: 2022-05-10 11:56:56Z

Answer (score 0):

**To redirect user to custom error page when user doesn't give consent during social logon, please try the following:**

- Try adding the below **snippet** in your **`startup.cs`** method:

```cs
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().Add(context =>
{
    if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path == "/AzureADB2C/Sociallogon/SignedIn")
    {
      context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/SignIn");
    }
}));
```

- Make sure to define a **claim type** of errorMessage and for this claim type define the text of the error message.
- Try configuring your **code** by referring this [***SO thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54419365/redirect-to-home-error-view-page-in-asp-net-core-2-0-mvc).

> Under  **[Redirect URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-microsoft-account?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)**, select  **Web**  and enter
> `https://your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp`. If you use a  **custom**
> **domain**, enter `https://your-domain-name/your-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp`.

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Creating an error page for an Azure AD B2C custom policy flow | by Rory Braybrook | The new control plane | Medium](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/creating-an-error-page-for-an-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy-flow-fb2692a3b50f)

[Invalid response signing in via Microsoft identity provider with Azure AD B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65767980/invalid-response-signing-in-via-microsoft-identity-provider-with-azure-ad-b2c)